# Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function diff() on string in

Tags: php, mysqli

Tengo un formulario que coge una hora automática y la otra la ingreso manual la hora de inicio guarda la hora local del equipo y la hora final se ingresa manual 
y guardan en en la base de datos para luego imprimirlos hasta acá todo bien

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Campos en base de datos** 
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

ahora necesito restar la hora fin con la hora de inicio es decir si comencé a las  8:30 am y termine a las  10:30 quiere decir que me demore 2 horas

este es el código que me hace la operación

**Vista crea la tabla y imprime los datos**

```
        <?php 
 date_default_timezone_set('America/bogota') 
  while ($r=mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {

$hinicio=date('h:i', strtotime($r['hinicio']));
 $hfin=date('h:i', strtotime($r['hfin']));
  $tiempo=date('h:i', strtotime($r['tiempo']));
                ?>

<input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $tiempo;?>" id="tiempo<?php echo $id;?>">
 <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $hinicio;?>" id="hinicio<?php echo $id;?>"> 
  <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $hfin;?>" id="hfin<?php echo $id;?>">


 <tr class="even pointer">
  <td><?php echo $hinicio;?></td>
   <td><?php echo $hfin;?></td>
    <td><?php echo $tiempo;?></td>
     <td ><span class="pull-right">
      <a href="#" class='btn btn-default' title='Editar producto' onclick="obtener_datos('<?php echo $id;?>');" data-toggle="modal" data-target=".bs-example-modal-lg-udp"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></i></a> 
       <a href="#" class='btn btn-default' title='Borrar producto' onclick="eliminar('<?php echo $id; ?>')"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></i> </a></span></td>
              </tr>
```

**inserción de datos y donde sale el error**

```
    include "../config/config.php";//Contiene funcion que conecta a la base de datos

 $hinicio=date("h:i:s");//8:30
 $hfin=$_POST["hfin"]; //10:30


    $dateInterval = $hinicio->diff($hfin);
    $tiempo = $dateInterval->format('Total: %H horas %i minutos');
    echo $tiempo; //Total: 02 horas

    $sql="insert into actividad (hinicio,hfin,tiempo,) 
     values (\"$hinicio\",\"$hfin\",\"$tiempo\")";
```

debería quedar así "la hora inicio y hora fin se guardan bien" el problema es la operación

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**error que me sale** la linea  25 es donde esta definida la variable $dateInterval

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

> **inserción de datos y código actualizado**
>
> ```
> include "../config/config.php";//Contiene funcion que conecta a la base de datos  
> $hinicio=new DateTime("G:i:s");
> $hfin=new DateTime("hfin");
> $tiempo = $hinicio->diff($hfin);
>
> $sql="insert into actividad (hinicio,hfin,tiempo)
>  values (\"$hinicio\",\"$hfin\",\"$tiempo\")";
> ```
>
> **código actualizado creo tabla imprimo resultado**
>
> ```
>   <?php 
> date_default_timezone_set('America/bogota');
> while ($r=mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
>
> $hinicio=date('G:i:s', strtotime($r['hinicio']));
> $hfin=date('G:i:s', strtotime($r['hfin']));
> $tiempo=date('G:i:s', strtotime($r['tiempo']));
>
>
>
> <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $hinicio;?>" id="hinicio<?php echo $id;?>">
> <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $hfin;?>" id="hfin<?php echo $id;?>">
> <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $tiempo;?>" id="tiempo<?php echo $id;?>">
>
> <tr class="even pointer">
> td><?php echo $hinicio;?></td>
> <td><?php echo $hfin;?></td>
> <td><?php echo $tiempo->format('Total: %H horas %i minutos');?></td>
> </tr>
>   <?php
>           } //en while
>                ?>
> ```

**error la linea  25  es donde esta la variable $hinicio de la inserción**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: No se si sea el problema, pero en los `<input type="hidden" value=""...>` falta un atributo importante, `name="xyz"` a menos que los estés capturando de otra forma.

Comment: pero en el campo de tiempo no necesito input este tiene que calcular y mostrar el resultado

Answer (score 4):

Como indica el Manual de PHP, [**`diff`**](https://www.php.net/manual/es/datetime.diff.php)

> Devuelve la diferencia **entre dos objetos DateTime**

Tu error es porque uno de los objetos que estás pasando no es `DateTime`, sino una cadena.

Puedes por tanto crear tus dos objetos con los valores recibidos y aplicar luego `diff`.

Ejemplo:

```
$dateStart=new DateTime("8:30");
$dateEnd=new DateTime("10:30");
$mDiff = $dateStart->diff($dateEnd);
echo $mDiff->format('Total: %H horas %i minutos');
```

**Salida:**

```
Total: 02 horas 0 minutos
```

Comment: Hola puedes mirar el bloque de código que publique donde puse los objetos DateTime

Comment: ¿No has podido resolver el problema @EstebanGiraldo?

Comment: No, es que me funciona poniendo el valor del datatime como ("8:30") pero cunado le pongo que me coja el valor del input ("hfin") sale este  error

Comment: @EstebanGiraldo es que esto está mal: `$hfin=new DateTime("hfin");` ahí tú tienes que pasarle el valor del POST, por ejemplo: `$hfin=new DateTime($_POST["hfin"]);` El constructor tiene que recibir un valor válido o una variable, pero no la cadena `hfin`.

Comment: Muchas gracias no había caído en cuenta

Answer (score 0):

Lo que sucede es que  diff() espera un objeto fecha y el estas enviando una cadena  `$hfin=$_POST["hfin"];` -> aquí se recibió el valor del input pero es un String

```
 $hfinal =$_POST["hfin"]; // aqui reciber el valor del input
 $hfin = date("h.i", strtotime($hfinal)); //conviertes ese valor a un objeto tipo date
 $dateInterval = $hinicio->diff($hfin); //calculas la diferencia
```

Comment: no te entendí el código  muy bien que me quieres decir

Comment: disculpa lo edite, es que escribi muy rapido

Comment: ahora si muchas gracias voy a ensayar